# What read/write/execute permissions should a standard Wordpress directory have?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, directory

We have a standard Wordpress site setup in our hosting. The previous owner had been changing the read/write permissions on all the files/directories. I've setup many Wordpress sites before but never mess with these permissions. Whats are the standard permissions the files should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a complete article about all do's and dont's with Wordpress file permissions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Personally, I use 755 on directories and 644 on files. Seems to always be working.